# c# webservice async

Tags: c#

I need to call a webservice but I dont care if I get need a response or the service is down (fire and forget).
Im currentlly using a try catch to compe with this.

My Question
Is there a better way?

Thanks
Sp

Bit more detail.
I dont want the call to fail even if the webservice is down

Comment: is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556353/fire-and-forget-asynch-asp-net-method-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a great case for one-way or "fire and forget" serivces:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyContract
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void MyMethod()
}
```

Leaves the client with no need to mess with async hoo-ha, just make the call and get on with life.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string webServ = "addressofwebservice";
   AsyncCallback asyncCall = new AsyncCallback(CallBack);
   webServ.BeginSomeFunkyMethod(data, asyncCall, webServ);
```

...

```
private void CallbackSampleMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
   if(asyncResult != null)
   {
       doFunkyStuff();
   }
   // else I really don't care...
}
```

How about that ?